# In python,why does the code in class body gets executed only when a method of another module is called?

Tags: python

Unlike Java, in python when a module is imported into another module and a module's method is called, why does the code in the body gets executed instead of only the code in the method?

Example (taken from another SO question):

#### file one.py

```
def func():
    print("func() in one.py")

print("top-level in one.py")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("one.py is being run directly")
else:
    print("one.py is being imported into another module")
```

#### file two.py

```
import one

print("top-level in two.py")
one.func()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("two.py is being run directly")
else:
    print("two.py is being imported into another module")
```

and when I run this :

```
python two.py
```

I get :

```
top-level in one.py
one.py is being imported into another module
top-level in two.py
func() in one.py
two.py is being run directly
```

If I want only the `func()` method of `one.py` to be executed and that's why I chose to import and then call it, what should I be doing?
Why does it get executed in the first place?
I know it gets called when its imported because of the statement `import one`. Looking for what prompted python designers to do it this way!

Comment: I totally don't understand why you're confused. Which line of code are you surprised is executed?

Comment: You don't seem to understand why `one.py` uses the `if __name__ == "__main__"` statement. The `else` clause is *specifically* for code that should only be executed on import (i.e., when `__name__` does *not* equal `__main__`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Programming languages can have several different kinds of syntactic elements. Most languages, for example, will have statements and expressions, which are distinct. Some languages, like Java, have other syntactic elements at the top level. You cannot, for example, write some statements at the top level or in a class, but if you wanted to put a class definition at the top level or method in a class, that would be just fine.

You could, perhaps, think of Java as having a declarative part at the top level that switches to imperative (statements) once you go deeper, and then likely an expression as you go even further. But Python doesn’t really work that way. Python does have a distinction between expressions and statements, but it doesn’t really have a top-level declarative syntactic element. Perhaps you’re thinking of this:

```
def greet(name):
    print("Hello, {}!".format(name))
```

…in the same way as you would in Java, in that it can only appear in a certain context. But no: in Python, a function definition is a statement, as is a class definition, as is an assignment.

Because of this design, it’s infeasible to “just import the definitions”: in order for the definitions to be created, the code to create the definitions must be run.

I urge you to think of the following case. In Python, if you want to create an enumeration (without the fancy new `enum` module), you might do something like this:

```
FOO, BAR, BAZ = range(3)
```

To the human eye, that’s probably a definition we want to exist when we import the module. But how is that fundamentally different from something like this, which you might expect to exist in `__main__`?

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
```

There really is no difference, so Python makes no attempt to try to distinguish them; when you import a module, the code is executed.

---

## Bonus: Similar behavior in Java

Think about this:

```java
public class Test {
    static {
        System.out.println("Wait, what? Code is running without being called?");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Nothing to see here, move along now...");
    }
}
```

Comment: "it’s infeasible to “just import the definitions”: in order for the definitions to be created, the code to create the definitions must be run." - This cleared it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It gets executed because *all* the code in the module gets executed, *including the function definition*, upon first import. If you don't want the code to be executed then put it in a main stanza.

Answer (score 2):

The key difference between Java and Python (in this instance) is that Java has a separate compile step -- using `javac` to create class files. Whereas, with Python this compiling is done at runtime. So when you import the module Python has to compile the entire module source code into byte code. This includes all those print statements as well as creating your functions and classes. What you're asking would be like asking `javac` to only compile part of a .java file.

Comment: I was thinking about including this in my answer, but it’s really fuzzy—you could certainly have an interpreted, compiled-to-bytecode-at-runtime language with a lot of enforced structure and ~same semantics as Java. On the other hand, you could probably also compile a Python-like language (maybe with some limitations like how RPython does it). While this is a useful distinction, I don’t think that’s what it really boils down to: I think it’s less a question of when it’s compiled and more a question of how restrictive the syntax is, what can be embedded in of what and the semantics of such.

Comment: @icktoofay I think you provided the better answer (I think your answer came up when I was halfway through typing mine). You make the much better point that the function is only created during execution of the module code, not during the module compilation. Two distinct, but interwoven steps in Python. I talked about compilation mainly because OP comes from a Java background where compilation is a distinct step to execution.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module in Python, the whole file is executed. This creates all the functions and variables that are part of the module. It doesn't differentiate between only executing function or class statements.

I believe the general pattern for having executable code within a library is this:

```
# one.py
def func():
    print "In file!"

def main():
    # do stuff here
    pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

You can then directly execute the file `python one.py` or you can `import one` and use `one.func()` from it.